# React.JS Cannot read property 'props' of null Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### just started using react.js.

i keep having the same error. don't know why ? 
the error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null`
i know that the error happens when i click the button. specifically i think it's in the update() method.

#### JS Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {increasing:false}
        this.do_update = this.update.bind(this);
    }
    update(){
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App val={this.props.val+1} />,
            document.getElementById('app')
        );
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState({increasing: (nextProps.val > this.props.val) })
    }
    render(){
        return <button onClick={this.update}>{this.props.val}</button>
    }
}

App.defaultProps = {val:0}
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: change {this.update} in your render method to {this.do_update}

Comment: Why are you never using `this.do_update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need pass to `onClick` `do_update` instead of `update`,

```
return <button onClick={ this.do_update }>{ this.props.val }</button>
```

or change name from `do_update` to `update`

```
this.update = this.update.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The update handler, when invoked, will not get the correct context for the 'this' keyword... which is why presumably your code has the:

```
this.do_update = this.update.bind(this);
```

line.

If you change your render method to the following, it should work:

```
render(){
        return <button onClick={this.do_update}>{this.props.val}</button>
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Change this line `this.state = {increasing:false}` to `this.state = {increasing: false}`

That space after the colon matters.

Comment: use this.setState( { increasing: false} ) when you want to update state